# The "size" of a continuous uniform selection of points in the unit square

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-functions

Let $\{X_r\}_{r\in[0,1]}$ be i.i.d. random variables, each distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. Let $S\subseteq[0,1]^2$ be the random set defined as follows:

$$S=\{(r,X_r)\mid r\in[0,1]\}$$

How would such a set look like? Will it be "space filling"? Formally, will it have Hausdorff dimension 2 (with high probability)? And if so, will it have (with high probability) a 2-dimensional Hausdorff measure 1?

Comment: Non measurable and dense.

Comment: Thanks; however, I believe that does not say anything about its Hausdorff dimension, right?